# Nodejs + PhantomJS in Docker: Error: spawn - ENOENT

Tags: node.js, docker, phantomjs

I am working on a Node.js application that uses [`html-pdf`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf), which uses `PhantomJS` when creating the pdf file given the `html` string.

Everything works fine, but when I want to build the application in `Docker`, this error occurs:

```
ERROR: Error: spawn /usr/src/app/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe ENOENT
events.js:291
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Error: write EPIPE
at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:25)
at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:147:3)
at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:785:11)
at Socket._write (net.js:797:8)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:352:12)
at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:303:10)
at PDF.PdfExec [as exec] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:141:15)
at PDF.PdfToFile [as toFile] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:83:8)
at /usr/src/app/src/createPDF.js:87:42
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:100:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:68:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

Here is the `Dockerfile` I am using:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .  

RUN npm install --production

RUN wget -O /tmp/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/
RUN tar xvjf /tmp/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 -C /tmp/phantomjs
RUN mv /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/* /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/
RUN rm -rf /tmp/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz && rm -rf /tmp/phantomjs

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm","run","serve"]
```

I prefer not to manually install `PhantomJS` but this is the only solution I found online.

I have also looked at other questions and tried to pass the `path` of `phantom` in the options but did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone facing this issue in the future, here is how I managed to fix this problem:

```
FROM node:latest
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .  

RUN npm install --production

RUN npm install -g phantomjs --unsafe-perm

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm","run","serve"]
```

Then pass the global path of `phantomjs` in the options using [`requireg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requireg):

```
var options = { phantomPath: require('requireg')('phantomjs').path }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this, and the key point is you have to do npm install on the docker image where you are going to run your application and expose the port!

```
FROM node:12.18.4 AS dep
```

## ENV PHANTOMJS_VERSION 2.1.1

COPY ./dist /app/
COPY ./package*.json /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install --production

FROM node:12.18.4-slim
COPY --from=dep /app /app
WORKDIR /app

## Install phantomjs

RUN apt-get update 
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends 
ca-certificates 
bzip2 
fontconfig 
libfontconfig 
&& apt-get clean 
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN npm install --production
RUN npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt --unsafe-perm

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["server.js"]